# How create an Executable file + Launcher in Ubuntu from a python script?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, debian

I have created a simple program in python.
Now I want trasform this script in an executable program ( with hidden source code if possible ) and when I click 2 times on it, the program install itself on the ubuntu ( in the /usr/lib or /usr/bin I think ) and it will create a new launcher in the Application -> Game menu.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Python scripts are already executable `chmod +x` is all you need.  You can't conceal Python scripts.  What have you tried?  What problems are you having?

Comment: I want create an executable program from this python script. This executable will install the program and will create a new launcher in Application -> Game menu. How can I do that :) ?

Comment: Please don't **repeat** your question.  I can read the words.  Please explain what you cannot do.  Executable is trivial.  What problem are you having?  **What have you tried?**  What part of that didn't work?  More importantly, what other "click 2 times on it, the program install itself" have you seen in Ubuntu?  Can you give an example of an ubuntu program that does this?

Answer (score 3):

Closed-source? Meh. Well, you can compile python iirc, or simply use an obscusificator. But I recommend to open-source it ;-)
The stuff you can double-click are `.desktop` files, for samples, see `find /usr | grep desktop`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you with concealing the python source, however, the application launcher is a [Desktop Entry](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) file with a `.desktop` extension. Your installer would install that to the `applications` folder in one of the system XDG_DIRS such as `/usr/share/` or `/usr/local/share`.

If you install your application's icon to a theme friendly location (such as `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/<size>/apps/<your application name>.png`) and install your executable to a location in PATH (often `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`) then you desktop entry file would not need absolute paths to the executable or icon.

As an example, let's take a python application called "myapp.py". Here is it's `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Application
Type=Application
Exec=myapp.py
Icon=myapp
```

Then say the application is built with autotools (`configure`, `make`, `make install`) with the "default" build options in which `prefix=/usr/local/share`. The following files would be installed:

```
/usr/local/share/applications/myapp.desktop
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/myapp.png
# same for sizes 22x22, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64
# it's also a good idea to include a "scalable" svg icon
/usr/local/bin/myapp  
# ^ this is your python "executable"
```

After running `update-desktop-database` as root (or from your Makefile) then your application will have a launcher and a nice pretty icon.

Answer (score 0):

use pyinstaller from pyinstaller.org

http://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/579554-simple-guide-using-pyinstaller

> pyinstaller helloworld.py

creates 2 folders 
bin and dist

run your exec form dist folder like

> ./helloworld